# Why is lint for ionic not showing any errors?

Tags: angular, docker, ionic-framework, lint, tslint

I have an ionic app in a docker container, that is supposed to have a linter running, every time I build the app. The linter is running alright, but I don't get any error message or any feedback at all from it. It just says:

```
[09:43:46]  lint finished in 15.66 s
```

and nothing more. There is no indication of any errors found (and I know for a fact that my code is full of errors) or that the linter has done anything at all.

I tried going into the docker container and manually running it with --verbose, but it didn't really give me anything too useful either:

```
root@4a3cca750e27:/usr/src/app# npm run lint --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'lint',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.10.1
npm verb run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
npm info lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~prelint: ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~lint: ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1

> ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1 lint /usr/src/app
> ionic-app-scripts lint

[10:12:07]  ionic-app-scripts 2.1.3
[10:12:08]  lint started ...
[10:12:21]  lint finished in 13.40 s
npm verb lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~lint: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bi
n:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~lint: CWD: /usr/src/app
npm info lifecycle ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1~postlint: ionic-agent-taskboard@0.0.1
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

I tried finding others with the same problem, but all I could find was this issue: 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/967
(moved from https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2218)

The issue has since been closed without any real answer at all.

Here's part of my package.json for version numbers:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.13.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "ionic": "3.19.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "0.0.14",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
  }
}
```

**Edit**

This is my tslint.json file, that ionic should pick up:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-duplicate-variable": true
  }
}
```

In `node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules`, there is a bunch of rules defined, that all come with ionic, so they should do something at least.

Comment: You need to define the `tslint-ionic-rules` when you run the lint. I don't do ionic, but I'd assume that there's a config file that `ionic-app-scripts` runs. Define it there

Comment: @Z.Bagley ionic is supposed to pick up any rules defined in the `tslint.json`. I've added my `tslint.json` file, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: If you still need help with this issue let me know. It seems like a debugging issue. I'd start from a brand new project, regular rules, and see if that works and go from there adding a custom rule, then a custom file, etc

Comment: @Z.Bagley I have resigned to declaring the linter broken and using another linter, but thank you very much.

Comment: @FritzLloyd could you share the linter you used and how you set it up?